# How to let Windows recognize a folder as Recycle Bin?

Tags: c, special-folders, fat32, recycle-bin, c-libraries

I have a FAT32 MicroSD card, where my device creates a folder named '$Recycle.Bin' in the root, with hidden+system attributes set, but Windows doesn't recognize it as a real recycle bin (with the correct icon, etc.).

How can I trick Windows into seeing the folder as genuine bin?

I am writing firmware for the device (an ARM datalogger), that has to create the folder using the FATFS library in C.  I could ask for example code, but I can write the code myself if someone can point me in the correct direction.  All forms of the answer are welcome.

Comment: @gibberish Please read my response to Felix

Comment: Thanks Muis, sorry for the misunderstanding. I edited the tags on your question to provide additional visibility and reduce future reader errors.

Comment: Without the content you provided in comments, I don't see how anyone would have been sure you were asking a programming question.  I think the question was incomplete without your comment, and may still need improvement regarding how what you have tried thus far.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows does not support Recycle Bins on removable media, like SD cards.  Only on HDDs, even external ones.